# Is the a default method in java Nashorn which is invoked when the actual method is not present?

Tags: java, nashorn

I'm looking for something in the Nashorn javascript engine in Java which would call a generic method as a fallback when the actual method cannot be found.

It should be something similar to groovy's `methodMissing` or `invokeMethod` features.

Is there anything like that?

I tried with java `Proxy`, but the `InvocationHandler` would be called only for methods in the interface... while I would want something like an `InvocationHandler` which should be called for any method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the **noSuchMethod** feature [documented here](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions). There is also a **noSuchProperty** hook for doing the same with properties and variables.

Comment: I was looking for something like this to implement on the Java side, but I guess I can work from here!